# Magento 2: How to copy the value of field to another field?

Tags: magento2

I need to copy the value of the Social Reason field to the firstname field so I can hide it and not leave it empty.

[image]

Is it possible with magento? or is a script necessary?

Comment: You only want to copy that value to First Name field? But on which page? You can managed it through js. Which field you want to hide?

Comment: @SukumarGorai I need to hide the name field, on the customer information page. And copy the value of social reason in name. Is it possible only with js or magento can it be done internally?

Comment: Customer information page means frontend account information or edit page?

Comment: In the backend, customer information page

Comment: During new customer creation or for existing customers?

Comment: For the new customer creation.

Comment: Then hide your attribute social reason and change the label of First name to Social reason.

Comment: How is it possible? in the database they are different and the two fields are required.